# Create Information content corpora to be used by webnet from a custom dump

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet, corpus, pos-tagger

I am using Brown corpus ic-brown.dat for calculating the information content of a word using wordnet nltk library. But results are not good looking. I was wondering how can i build my own custome.dat (information content file).

```
custom_ic = wordnet_ic.ic('custom.dat')
```

Answer (score 2):

In **(...)/nltk_data/corpora/wordnet_ic/** you will find **IC-compute.sh**  that contains some calls to some Perl scripts to generate the IC dat files from a given corpus. I founded the instructions tricky, and I do not have the require Perl scripts, so I decided to create a python script by analyzing the dat files structure and wordnet.ic() function.

You can compute your own IC counts by calling the **wordnet.ic()** function over a corpus reader object. In fact, you only need an object with a word() function that returns all the words in the corpus. For more details check the ic function (line 1729 to 1789) in the file ..../nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py.

For example, for the XML version of the BNC corpus (2007):

```
reader_bnc = nltk.corpus.reader.BNCCorpusReader(root='../Corpus/2554/2554/download/Texts/', fileids=r'[A-K]/\w*/\w*\.xml')
bnc_ic = wn.ic(reader_bnc, False, 0.0)
```

To generate the .dat file I created the following functions:

```
def is_root(synset_x):
    if synset_x.root_hypernyms()[0] == synset_x:
        return True
    return False

def generate_ic_file(IC, output_filename):
    """Dump in output_filename the IC counts.
    The expected format of IC is a dict 
    {'v':defaultdict, 'n':defaultdict, 'a':defaultdict, 'r':defaultdict}"""
    with codecs.open(output_filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fid:
        # Hash code of WordNet 3.0
        fid.write("wnver::eOS9lXC6GvMWznF1wkZofDdtbBU"+"\n")

        # We only stored nouns and verbs because those are the only POS tags
        # supported by wordnet.ic() function
        for tag_type in ['v', 'n']:#IC:
            for key, value in IC[tag_type].items():
                if key != 0:
                    synset_x = wn.of2ss(of="{:08d}".format(key)+tag_type)
                    if is_root(synset_x):
                        fid.write(str(key)+tag_type+" "+str(value)+" ROOT\n")
                    else:
                        fid.write(str(key)+tag_type+" "+str(value)+"\n")
    print("Done")

generate_ic_file(bnc_ic, "../custom.dat")
```

Then, just call the function:

```
custom_ic = wordnet_ic.ic('../custom.dat')
```

The imports needed are:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from nltk.corpus import wordnet_ic
import codecs
```